# Connecting webform(in php/html) with desktop form(of any application/software)

Tags: php, .net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Suppose ,I want to login/connect in filezila

http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1oiQZKz4WcjABjEORg5tmaDzPpTAKn1

& the following is the webform(in php)
http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1XAPZ2EkDkHMOGdNpMlIGWYVjnz31

Is it possible to connect these two forms(one on desktop,another on web) & login/connect the filezilla from the web?

Please detail your answer/s as much as possible..
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! 

Please keep in mind that ou can upload and embed pictures directly into your post by pressing the image button or how you normally would using HTML (with `<img>`), so you don't have to link to other hosting sites.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is possible, but it would take a little work to get it right. You would need to code a script or app which would connect the two together.

Say when the user enters their login details into the web page, those details are then written to a text file on your web server.

Your connecting App could poll your web server for that file and when it changes (say maybe a timestamp change) it will open the file, read the login details and then pass them to filezilla as start up parameters.